# Fail to understand Octave structure declaration

Tags: data-structures, structure, octave

There is a new feature in Octave - Structure. I got the information about Structure from [Octave Structure](https://octave.org/doc/v4.2.1/Creating-Structures.html).

I also got some code to create a structure like that

```
data = struct;
data.timestep.sensor = struct;
```

But I never got this type of declaration in [Octave Structure](https://octave.org/doc/v4.2.1/Creating-Structures.html). So I become confused about these two coding lines.

Can anyone please help me to understand these two line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, structures aren't that new in Octave (the linked documentation page is already available for Octave 4.0.0 with [last modified date March 2016](https://octave.org/doc/)).

Have you just played around a bit creating structures? The first line will just generate some empty structure.

```matlab
data = struct
        data =
          scalar structure containing the fields:
```

As you can see, there are no fields, yet.

The second line (implicitly)

1. adds a field `timestep` to the structure `data`,
2. adds a field `sensor` to `timestep`, (implicitly) making `timestep` a (sub)structure,
3. makes the field `sensor` an empty structure itself.

If there's no `data` variable in your workspace before (or already a proper structure), the second line is sufficient. Then, `data` is also implicitly generated as a structure.

```matlab
clear data;
data.timestep.sensor = struct
        data =
          scalar structure containing the fields:
            timestep =
              scalar structure containing the fields:
                sensor =
                  scalar structure containing the fields:
```

If there's already a `data` variable, e.g. with some scalar, that won't work, and you'd need both lines.

```matlab
data = 42;
data.timestep.sensor = struct
error: scalar cannot be indexed with .

data = struct
        data =
          scalar structure containing the fields:

data.timestep.sensor = struct
        data =
          scalar structure containing the fields:
            timestep =
              scalar structure containing the fields:
                sensor =
                  scalar structure containing the fields:
```

Instead of `data = struct`, you could've also used `clear data` for example.

Hope that helps! If not, maybe provide some more details in your question, what EXACTLY confuses you.